# Where does chrome emulator put the downloaded file?

Tags: google-chrome, cordova, web-applications, frontend

Right now, I develop a android webapp using PhoneGap.
I use chrome emulator for daily development.
Within the app, I can download file by click attachment link.
I just wonder where actually does chrome emulator put the download file?
There is nothing in the chrome download history.

Thanks a lot for any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using chrome emulator to download file, chrome does nothing. So no downloading actually happended.